# grep: extract content between prefix and suffix

Tags: grep

I've a file content like this:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
------------------------------------------------------------
 ^[[1m HAPI FHIR^[[22m 5.4.0 - Command Line Tool
------------------------------------------------------------
Process ID                      : 21719@psgd
Max configured JVM memory (Xmx) : 3.2GB
Detected Java version           : 11.0.7
------------------------------------------------------------
^[[32m2021-07-01^[[0;39m ^[[1;32m12:27:40.79^[[0;39m ^[[37m[main]^[[0;39m ^[[37mWARN ^[[0;39m ^[[1;34mo.f.c.i.s.c.ClassPathScanner^[[0;39m ^[[1;37mUnable to resolve location classpath:db/migration. Note this warning will become an error in Flyway 7.
^[[0;39m^[[32m2021-07-01^[[0;39m ^[[1;32m12:27:42.641^[[0;39m ^[[37m[main]^[[0;39m ^[[37mWARN ^[[0;39m ^[[1;34mo.f.c.i.s.c.ClassPathScanner^[[0;39m ^[[1;37mUnable to resolve location classpath:db/migration. Note this warning will become an error in Flyway 7.
^[[0;39m^[[32m2021-07-01^[[0;39m ^[[1;32m12:27:44.693^[[0;39m ^[[37m[main]^[[0;39m ^[[37mINFO ^[[0;39m ^[[1;34mc.u.f.j.m.t.InitializeSchemaTask^[[0;39m ^[[1;37m3_3_0.20180115.0: Initializing ORACLE_12C schema for HAPI FHIR
^[[0;39m^[[32m2021-07-01^[[0;39m ^[[1;32m12:27:44.848^[[0;39m ^[[37m[main]^[[0;39m ^[[37mINFO ^[[0;39m ^[[1;34mc.u.f.j.m.t.BaseTask^[[0;39m ^[[1;37m3_3_0.20180115.0: SQL "create sequence SEQ_BLKEXCOL_PID start with 1 increment by  50" returned 0
^[[0;39m^[[32m2021-07-01^[[0;39m ^[[1;32m12:27:44.918^[[0;39m ^[[37m[main]^[[0;39m ^[[37mINFO ^[[0;39m ^[[1;34mc.u.f.j.m.t.BaseTask^[[0;39m ^[[1;37m3_3_0.20180115.0: SQL "
create sequence SEQ_BLKEXCOLFILE_PID start with 1 increment by  50" returned 0
^[[0;39m^[[32m2021-07-01^[[0;39m ^[[1;32m12:27:47.573^[[0;39m ^[[37m[main]^[[0;39m ^[[37mINFO ^[[0;39m ^[[1;34mc.u.f.j.m.t.BaseTask^[[0;39m ^[[1;37m3_3_0.20180115.0: SQL "

    create table HFJ_BINARY_STORAGE_BLOB (
       BLOB_ID varchar2(200 char) not null,
        BLOB_DATA blob not null,
        CONTENT_TYPE varchar2(100 char) not null,
        BLOB_HASH varchar2(128 char),
        PUBLISHED_DATE timestamp not null,
        RESOURCE_ID varchar2(100 char) not null,
        BLOB_SIZE number(10,0),
        primary key (BLOB_ID)
    )" returned 0
```

I need to extract only content inside between `SQL "` and `" returned 0` trimming all whitespaces.

Any ideas?

I've tried to reduce problem using:

```
$ echo 'sdf SQL" sdf sdf" returned 0' | grep 's/SQL"\(.*\)" returned 0/\1/' -
```

But it's getting empty.

My expected output is:

```
create sequence SEQ_BLKEXCOL_PID start with 1 increment by  50;
create sequence SEQ_BLKEXCOLFILE_PID start with 1 increment by  50;
create table HFJ_BINARY_STORAGE_BLOB (
       BLOB_ID varchar2(200 char) not null,
        BLOB_DATA blob not null,
        CONTENT_TYPE varchar2(100 char) not null,
        BLOB_HASH varchar2(128 char),
        PUBLISHED_DATE timestamp not null,
        RESOURCE_ID varchar2(100 char) not null,
        BLOB_SIZE number(10,0),
        primary key (BLOB_ID)
    );
```

I've tried to perform:

```
cat test.log | sed -E 's/.* SQL"(.*)" returned 0/\1/'
```

It's returning me all file content...

Using `awk`, it returns empty:

```
$ awk -v RS='SQL "[[:space:]]+?\n\n+.*returned 0' '                                                                                                  
RT{
 gsub(/^SQL "\n+|\n+$/,"",RT)
 sub(/" returned 0[[:space:]]+?\n*$/,"",RT)
 print RT";"
}
' test.log
```

Comment: please add your attempt in the answer

Comment: `echo 'sdf1 SQL"sdf2 sdf3" returned 0' | sed -E 's/.* SQL"(.*)" returned 0/\1/'` should work. What's your expected output?

Comment: I've added some details on post...

Comment: `+?` in your regexp is a repetition character `+` (meaning 1 or more) followed immediately be a 2nd repetition character `?` (meaning 0 or 1) and so the result of that is undefined behavior. Maybe you meant to write `*` (meaning 0 or more) instead of `+?`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using custom `RS` in `gnu-awk` that splits data on `SQL "..."` text block and then inside action block it extracts text between quotes without leading space.

```sh
awk -v RS=' SQL "[^"]+"' 'RT {
gsub(/^[^"]*"[[:space:]]*|"[^"]*$/, "", RT); print RT ";"}' file.sql

create sequence SEQ_BLKEXCOL_PID start with 1 increment by  50;
create sequence SEQ_BLKEXCOLFILE_PID start with 1 increment by  50;
create table HFJ_BINARY_STORAGE_BLOB (
       BLOB_ID varchar2(200 char) not null,
        BLOB_DATA blob not null,
        CONTENT_TYPE varchar2(100 char) not null,
        BLOB_HASH varchar2(128 char),
        PUBLISHED_DATE timestamp not null,
        RESOURCE_ID varchar2(100 char) not null,
        BLOB_SIZE number(10,0),
        primary key (BLOB_ID)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`, with your shown samples, please try following code once.

```
awk -v RS='SQL "[[:space:]]*\n\n+.*returned 0' '
RT{
 gsub(/^SQL "\n+|\n+$/,"",RT)
 sub(/" returned 0[[:space:]]*\n*$/,"",RT)
 print RT";"
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting RS as `SQL "[[:space:]]+?\n\n+.*returned 0` for `awk` program, removing not required strings like `SQL "` with new lines and  returned 0 at last of value before printing it.

Explanation of regex is as follows: match SQL followed by space `"` followed by 1 or more spaces(optional) followed by 1 or more new lines till `returned 0` here.

Comment: It doesn't work to me. It's returning empty result. I edited post with details.

Comment: @Jordi, With your shown samples input its working fine for me. Could you please run `awk --v` once to check what version of awk you have.

Comment: I've created an ascinema [here](https://asciinema.org/a/9YWx2S6Y5bi0G1NR8fuxrQWvG)

Comment: @Jordi, sure, saw that. But its working for me, could you please paste me output of `awk --v` to know version of awk once.

Comment: @Jordi, ohhh that's strange. Please try `awk --version` once and let me know what it gives you?

Comment: @Jordi, ok, what is your O.S? is it Sun o.s?

Comment: @Jordi, I am also using ubuntu :) and these commands are working fine for me honestly.

Comment: @Jordi, could you please try running `awk -v RS='SQL "' '{print RT}'  file` once what it gives you? Let me know.

Comment: You can see it [here](https://asciinema.org/a/KtmQpv17zFnPqhj9aV3aUaHzb)

Comment: @Jordi, strange, how about running `which awk` what output it gives you?

Comment: @Jordi, ok now how about running `/usr/bin/awk --v` OR `/usr/bin/awk --version` once.

Comment: @Jordi, could you please try `awk '/SQL "/{found1=1} found1 && /create table/{found2=1} found2{if($0~/returned 0/){sub(/\).*/,");")};print}' file` once and let me know if this helps you? I hope this should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234417/discussion-between-jordi-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @Jordi, sorry I can't join chat room, we could comment here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `gnu grep` then you can use this PCRE regex:

```sh
grep -oPz ' SQL "\K[^"]+' file.sql

create sequence SEQ_BLKEXCOL_PID start with 1 increment by  50
create sequence SEQ_BLKEXCOLFILE_PID start with 1 increment by  50

    create table HFJ_BINARY_STORAGE_BLOB (
       BLOB_ID varchar2(200 char) not null,
        BLOB_DATA blob not null,
        CONTENT_TYPE varchar2(100 char) not null,
        BLOB_HASH varchar2(128 char),
        PUBLISHED_DATE timestamp not null,
        RESOURCE_ID varchar2(100 char) not null,
        BLOB_SIZE number(10,0),
        primary key (BLOB_ID)
    )
```

**Explanation:**

- `' SQL "`: Search  `SQL "` text
- `\K`: Reset matched info
- `[^"]+`: Match 1+ of any characters that are not `"`

---

To get formatting as desired (in comments) use this `grep + sed (gnu)` solution:

```sh
grep -oPzZ ' SQL "\K[^"]+' file.sql |
sed -E '$s/$/\n/; s/\x0/;/; s/^[[:blank:]]+//'

create sequence SEQ_BLKEXCOL_PID start with 1 increment by  50;
create sequence SEQ_BLKEXCOLFILE_PID start with 1 increment by  50;

create table HFJ_BINARY_STORAGE_BLOB (
BLOB_ID varchar2(200 char) not null,
BLOB_DATA blob not null,
CONTENT_TYPE varchar2(100 char) not null,
BLOB_HASH varchar2(128 char),
PUBLISHED_DATE timestamp not null,
RESOURCE_ID varchar2(100 char) not null,
BLOB_SIZE number(10,0),
primary key (BLOB_ID)
);
```

Comment: Just be aware that according to the GNU grep providers `grep -Pz` is experimental (see `-P` at https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs) and that output produced using `-Z` is not a POSIX text file due to no terminating newline and so what any subsequent text processing tool such as sed does with it is undefined behavior per POSIX.

Comment: That's right Ed, these are experimental features and not fully POSIX compliant. That was the reason I moved it into separate answer.

Comment: Understood, it's just worth giving people a heads up IMHO as neither thing is intuitively obvious.